# How do I get started on add-on/plug-in/browser extension

Tags: web-applications

Newbie question:

I am trying to write a browser-based application that will run only when a new page is being downloaded but before the page is rendered on the browser.

I am thoroughly confused whether I should look for 'browser extension' versus 'plug-in' versus 'add-on'. Adding to the confusion is the fact that it looks like the application needs to be re-written for Mozilla family and IE separately.

Where do I start? (BTW, the only tool that I have now is Visual Studio 2010 Express).

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the source code that does something similar to what you want to do like [adblock](http://adblockplus.org/en/source).  Once you can compile and install that as is, then you can take out the code you don't want and put in yours.